# R dataframe insert values based on other dataframe

Tags: r, dataframe

I've got 2 dataframes as follows:

```
df1
name    date       value df2_row df2_col
a    31-01-2019      1      1       1
b    31-01-2019      3      2       1
c    31-03-2019      5      3       3
d    31-03-2019      6      4       3
```

```
df2
name    31-01-2019 28-02-2019 31-03-2019       
a    
b    
c    
d
```

and I would like receive df2 like this:

```
df2
name    31-01-2019     28-02-2019    31-03-2019       
a             1            NA             NA
b             3            NA             NA                 
c             NA           NA             5
d             NA           NA             6
```

Any Ideas?

Comment: What are your ideas? What did you try? Please share the code that you used and failed. Also make sure to give reproducible examples and that the expected output matches those examples.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like `name` and `date` in `df1` are not related to the final output. Assuming you have one column (`name`) before `NA` columns, `cbind` `df2_row` and `df2_col` and assign `value` to them.

```
df2[cbind(df1$df2_row, df1$df2_col)] <- df1$value

#  31-01-2019 28-02-2019 31-03-2019
#1          1         NA         NA
#2          3         NA         NA
#3         NA         NA          5
#4         NA         NA          6
```

**data**

Assuming your `df2` is like this

```
df2 <- cbind(name = c("a", "b", "c", "d"), 
       setNames(data.frame(matrix(NA, ncol = 3, nrow = 4)), 
       c("31-01-2019","28-02-2019","31-03-2019"))) 

df2
#  name 31-01-2019 28-02-2019 31-03-2019
#1    a         NA         NA         NA
#2    b         NA         NA         NA
#3    c         NA         NA         NA
#4    d         NA         NA         NA
```

Answer (score 0):

We can convert the subset of data to `matrix` and it should work as a row/column index

```
df2[-1][as.matrix(df1[c("df2_row", "df2_col")])] <- df1$value
df2
#  name 31-01-2019 28-02-2019 31-03-2019
#1    a          1         NA         NA
#2    b          3         NA         NA
#3    c         NA         NA          5
#4    d         NA         NA          6
```